# Internet access lost on host after docker installation on linux Mint 17

Tags: linux, docker

On linux Mint 17, I installed Docker following the steps described in https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/ubuntulinux/

The installation was successfull but then I lost access to the Internet on the host machine!

The wired connection is still active but no Internet access. I removed docker and the internet access is back.

Here is some info about my Linux :

```
# cat /etc/*release
DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint
DISTRIB_RELEASE=17
DISTRIB_CODENAME=qiana
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 17 Qiana"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

The docker0 bridge exists

```
~ # brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
docker0     8000.000000000000   no
```

My linux is setup to forward the network

```
net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding = 1
```

Since it is a laptop I have a LAN nic card and a wifi card, the bug is that I get network access if I am on the WIFI card but not when I am connected to the LAN network. I have looked at the /etc/init/docker.conf or /etc/defaults/docker and I cannot find a setting where to give access to docker on my eth0 connection.

Regards

Comment: I have the same problem. Any update? 
I've followed the same link as you. Added file /etc/docker/daemon.json with 
{
     " dns": ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4", "192.168.1.1"]
}

I have no network connection. I believe the docker proxy is not working.

Comment: I'm astonished how this is not a documented issue. Some answers like https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/379351/installed-docker-then-lost-internet-connection-on-reboot-ubuntu-16-04-2-lts imply tweaking GRUB configuration files, which seems a bit overkill to me.